# Ag-grid not showing loading message

Tags: ag-grid

I am using a javascript ag-grid. I am fetching some data from an api call to show up on the grid. When the setRow method of the ag-grid is called, I get 'No Rows to Show' message. and after some time the data gets loaded in the grid. I want to see 'Loading' message when the rows are being fetched and 'No Rows to show' only if no data is present.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/overlays/#overlay-api you can use `showLoadingOverlay` and `showNoRowsOverlay`